# "Unmanaged memory" at profiler diagram. Is this a memory leak indication?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, profiling

I've faced with this diagram, when profiling memory usage of my application:

[image]

As you can see, before line "snapshot 1" unmanaged memory holds approximately a half of total used memory. Then, after "snapshot 1" and 2 min 55 s (see the timeline below), I've forced a garbage collection.

As I expect, generation 2 was mostly collected, but unmanaged memory was not released, and now it holds approx. 2/3 of total used memory.

I have no idea, what "unmanaged memory" means in this context.
This is the WPF application with some WinForms/GDI+ interop. I'm sure, that everything, that should be disposed, is disposed. Also, there's no explicit platform interop code. The rest of managed memory is OK.

Is this a memory leak indication?
If so, what is the way to detect memory leak here?
Is this matters, the profiler I'm using is JetBrains dotMemory.

Comment: WPF uses DirectX.  Maybe that is the source of unmanaged memory?  _[WPF relies entirely on Direct3D for rendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa663364.aspx)_

Comment: It is only a real leak if it builds up constantly and ultimately bombs your program.  Profilers in general have very few decent ways to tell you anything about unmanaged memory.  And sure, a WPF app will use a lot of it.  Retained mode graphics rendering is nice, it doesn't come for free.   Not exactly a real problem on modern machines.  Focus on leaks in your own code, there isn't anything you can do, or should do, about the WPF plumbing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Total used" memory on dotMemory chart it's the private working set of process. It's memory that the process executable has asked for - not necessarily the amount it is actually using. It includes all your DLLs and heaps but not includes memory-mapped files (shared DLLs). Moreover there is no way to tell whether it belongs to executable itself, or to a linked library. It's not exclusively physical memory; they can be paged to disk or in the standby page list (i.e. no longer in use, but not paged yet either).
So, unmanaged memory is everything in private working set except managed CLR heaps. Usually you have no easy ways to change amount of unmanaged memory for pure .net process. And it's approximately constant during execution of program.

Comment: I doubt that "Private working set" is correct. Working set describes something that is in physical RAM. And what the application has asked for is not necessarily in physical RAM. It might be swapped to disk.